# Kubernetes - mount container stdout stderr logs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, stdout, stderr

I use "[chentex/random-logger](https://hub.docker.com/r/chentex/random-logger/)" image, which write stdout/stderr to the container. I want to make deployment yaml, which run the chentex's image, and put it's logs in file inside shared volume. Can I do it without modifying the image?

This is the simple deployment of the image:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: random-logger
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: random-logger
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: random-logger
        image: chentex/random-logger:latest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best practice to send log message to `stdout` for applications running in a container. The `chentex/random-logger` just [follows this approach](https://github.com/chentex/random-logger/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L10-L16) without any option to configure this, but we can bring up a hack like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: random-logger
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: random-logger
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: random-logger
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: random-logger
        image: chentex/random-logger:latest
        command: ["sh", "-c",  "./entrypoint.sh &> /logfile"]
```

When requesting the logs from the running `pod` there is nothing to see:

```sh
$ kubectl logs random-logger-76c6fd98d5-8d5fm
```

The application logs are written to `logfile` within the container:

```sh
$ kubectl exec random-logger-76c6fd98d5-8d5fm cat /logfile
2019-02-28T00:23:23+0000 DEBUG first loop completed.
2019-02-28T00:23:25+0000 ERROR something happened in this execution.
2019-02-28T00:23:29+0000 INFO takes the value and converts it to string.
2019-02-28T00:23:31+0000 WARN variable not in use.
2019-02-28T00:23:37+0000 INFO takes the value and converts it to string.
```

Although this is possible, it is in general not advised. See the Kubernetes documentation about [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) for more background information.